# Does $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \in Z(G)$ for all $y$ in some group $G$ imply that $x \in Z(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \in Z(G)\ \forall\ y \in G$. Does this imply that $x \in Z(G)$? Why is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Consider the quaternion group, $Q_8$.

> Every commutator $x^{-1} y^{-1} x y$ of elements $x, y \in Q_8$ is equal to $1$ or $-1$, and these two elements together comprise the center $Z(Q_8)$ of $Q_8$. So, the given commutator condition actually holds for *every* element of $Q_8$, but not every element of $Q_8$ is in the group's center.